# react native touchable highlight and touchable native feedback for making my menu items

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement a basic drawer, but I am confused by the documentation.

There is a TouchableHighlight, and there is a TouchableNativeFeedback.

TouchableNativeFeedback is Android only.  So, how can I best handle my MenuItem component so it takes care of both Android and IOS?

Here's what I've got so far, and I'm not sure how to handle the different platform specific touchable stuff here:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { TouchableHighlight, TouchableNativeFeedback, Platform, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export class MenuItem extends Component {

  handleAndroid() {

  }

  handleIOS() {

  }

  renderMenuItem() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          {this.props.text}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (

    );
  }
}
```

On Android, do I have to use TouchableNativeFeedback only?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Like you said, `TouchableNativeFeedback` is Android only therefore it won't work for iOS. If you want a solution that works for both, use `TouchableHighlight` and style it accordingly. For example, its `underlayColor` prop allows you to set *"the color of the underlay that will show through when the touch is active."*

**EDIT:**

If you want to use `TouchableNativeFeedback` for Android and `TouchableHighlight` for iOS, you should do something like the following:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
...

render() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
       return (
          <TouchableNativeFeedback> 
               ... 
          </TouchableNativeFeedback>    
       )
    } else {
       return (
          <TouchableHighlight> 
               ... 
          </TouchableHighlight>    
       )
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Alternatively, you can create a custom component for each platform and use file extensions. For example:

```
MyButton.ios.js
MyButton.android.js
```

Put these two in the same folder and then use `MyButton` as a regular component:

```
import MyButton from '../path/to/component/MyButton'
...

render() {
   <MyButton/>
}
```

This is quite neat when you want to use this component in multiple places because you don't fill your code with if-else blocks.

Here you can read more about [Platform Specific Code](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html).

Comment: thanks.  is there a way to handle it properly so that if the Platform.OS is android, it will use touchableNativeFeedback?

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this in a more elegant manner like this:

```
render() {
    let TouchablePlatformSpecific = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 
        TouchableOpacity : 
        TouchableNativeFeedback;

    let touchableStyle = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 
        styles.iosTouchable : 
        styles.androidTouchable

    return(
        <TouchablePlatformSpecific style={touchableStyle}>
            (...)
        </TouchablePlatformSpecific>   
    );
}
```

I've been using this successfully, and I fail to see a reason it would not work, it looks good to me.

Comment: Yes, that would work, too, but I fail to see how two condition checks are more elegant than one.

Comment: the "elegant" part I am referring to is being able to use just one component on the JSX part, avoiding duplicity of the interface code. In the accepted answer, you would have to write everything that's inside the Touchable component twice.

Comment: If there's common code in the two Touchable components, then you can just put this piece in a separate method and re-use it.

Answer (score 5):

We can have a dumb component that produces generic Touchable that works depending upon the platform and handle onPress events.

**Touchable Component:**

```
import { Platform } from "react-native"


import { TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"
import React from "react"

export const Touchable = (props: any) => {
  return Platform.OS === 'android'
    ? <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={props.onPress}>{props.children}</TouchableNativeFeedback>
    : <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>{props.children}</TouchableOpacity>
}
```

**Usage:**

```
import { Touchable } from '../path/to/touchable.component';
...
render() {
    <Touchable onPress={() => this.handleClick()}>
         .....
    </Touchable>
}
```

Thanks to @Giorgos' implementation which formed the basis for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could create a custom component like this:

```
import { TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
...
const Touchable = (props) => {
  return Platform.OS === 'android'
    ? <TouchableNativeFeedback>{props.children}</TouchableNativeFeedback>
    : <TouchableOpacity>{props.children}</TouchableOpacity>
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
<Touchable>
    <Card>
       <Text>Click me!</Text>
    </Card>
</Touchable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Nithish JV and Giorgos Karyofyllis:

```
import React from "react"
import { Platform } from "react-native"
import { TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"

export const TouchableFeedback = (props: any) => {
    const { children, ...rest } = props;
    return Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? <TouchableNativeFeedback {...rest}>{children}</TouchableNativeFeedback>
        : <TouchableOpacity {...rest}>{children}</TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best elegant way to do it

`import { TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'`

in render:

```
TouchableButton = Platform.OS === 'android' ? TouchableNativeFeedback : TouchableOpacity
return (
    <TouchableButton>{'bla bla'}</TouchableButton>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the operating system doesn't change magically during runtime, I always use this little snippet:

```js
import { Component } from "react"
import {
    Platform,
    TouchableNativeFeedback,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native"

// The operating system doesn't magically change,
// so we can call the function directly to get the correct component
export default ((): typeof Component => {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        return TouchableNativeFeedback
    }

    return TouchableOpacity // Choose whatever touchable you like
})()
```

It's basically an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) that selects the correct touchable for the operating system.

Answer (score -1):

I also have nearly the same requirements and I ended up using this library [react-native-haptic-feedback](https://github.com/milk-and-cookies-io/react-native-haptic-feedback).

Keep in mind that haptic feedback is available only on some latest android devices and in iOS above iPhone 6s. For devices without haptic motor, there will be vibration. Here is a sample code snippet:

```
import ReactNativeHapticFeedback from "react-native-haptic-feedback";

const options = {
  enableVibrateFallback: true,
  ignoreAndroidSystemSettings: false
};

ReactNativeHapticFeedback.trigger("impactMedium", options);
```

In your case, it will work directly with the button's onPress method such as:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ReactNativeHapticFeedback.trigger("impactMedium", options);}} />
```

> Note: I found that the most versatile type which is supported by maximum devices is `impactMedium`.